# Populate external table using data from another table in Hive

Tags: mysql, hive

I have a table that has tons of data. Call this table A. I want to create an external table (say table B) that has data from some columns of table A. I tried using 'create table as' (CTAS) but getting error that CTAS doesn't work with external tables. How can I do this simple job?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply inserting everything from table A into table B, selecting the columns that you want to copy over. Assuming you have already got table A, it should look something like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_b
(column_one type, column_three type)
LOCATION 'location_you_need_to_give';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_b
SELECT (column_one, column_three) FROM table_a;
```

Where column_one and column_three are the columns from table_a that you want copied over, and location_you_need_to_give is an external location (an HDFS path, or S3 path if you are using amazon elastic map reduce), where you want table_b to store the data.